# Is there a raster value modification function faster than terra::subst?

Tags: r, terra, subst

I have 280 large (400MB) raster files in TIFF format.
I am currently using terra::subst to modify the values of each raster file.

For example:

```r
raster_matrix<-matrix(rep(101:200,10000*1600),nrow=1000*40,ncol=1000*40)
raster<-terra::rast(raster_matrix)
raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster, c(151, 152, 153), NA))
raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster_subst, c(160, 161, 162), 1))
raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster_subst, c(170, 171, 172), 2))
```

However, this process takes too long when applied to all 280 files.
Is there a faster and more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, hsk! Questions on SO do much better when they are reproducible, including sample data. I don't think much is needed here, but since we don't know `file_location` and couldn't read it if we did, it might be useful to provide sample data manually. In `?rast` they include `rast(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmin=0, xmax=10)`, perhaps that would suffice for sample data?

Comment: Are you making changes based on something in the raster or by some external property? How many of these three-set substitutions do you have to do? Do you have those stored in a matrix/frame/object somewhere?

Comment: I am making changes based on something in my raster.

Comment: And the 'something' being...? as the underlying logic might point to a different solution.

Comment: "something" are integer as written in the example codes (e.g., 151, 152, 153 ...)

Comment: And are they different across the 280 such that `NA, 1, 2, ...`, and are they (the undesired integers) scattered or clumped?

Answer (score 2):

This takes 1/3 of the time on the example dataset below. I could not recreate a SpatRaster as big as your example on my machine so am unsure how it will scale. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will know how to reduce the time even further.

```
library(terra)
library(microbenchmark)

raster_matrix<-matrix(rep(101:200,5000*1600),nrow=500*40,ncol=500*40)
raster <- terra::rast(raster_matrix)

results <- microbenchmark(
  separate <- {raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster, c(151, 152, 153), NA);
  raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster_subst, c(160, 161, 162), 1);
  raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster_subst, c(170, 171, 172), 2)},
  together <- subst(raster, 
                        c(151, 152, 153, 160, 161, 162,170, 171, 172), 
                        rep(c(NA, 1, 2), each = 3)),
  times = 10)

results
Unit: seconds
              min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
separate 41.73862 41.91065 42.43262 42.24467 43.16119 43.41679    10
together 13.56677 13.82499 13.89107 13.90967 14.02498 14.18583    10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the values for ranges (e.g. 150 to 152), `terra::classify` may be faster. Note argument `right=NA` to have the interval open at the left and right.

Illustrated by building on l-tyrone's benchmarking.

```
library(terra)
library(microbenchmark)

raster_matrix <- matrix(101:200,nrow=500,ncol=500)
raster <- terra::rast(raster_matrix)

m1 <- cbind(c(151, 152, 153, 160, 161, 162,170, 171, 172), 
                        rep(c(NA, 1, 2), each = 3))

m2 <- matrix(c(151, 153, NA, 160, 162, 1, 170, 172, 2), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
 

microbenchmark(
  separate = {terra::subst(raster, c(151, 152, 153), NA);
        raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster_subst, c(160, 161, 162), 1);
        raster_subst <- terra::subst(raster_subst, c(170, 171, 172), 2)},
  together = subst(raster, m1[,1], m1[,2]),
  reclass1 = classify(raster, m1),  
  reclass2 = classify(raster, m2, right=NA),  
  times = 10
)

#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr     min      lq     mean   median      uq     max neval cld
# separate 14.9612 15.0116 15.66967 15.22865 15.5153 19.4597    10 a  
# together  5.8914  6.0275  6.26044  6.20995  6.4754  6.7361    10  b 
# reclass1  5.9294  6.1203  6.24878  6.21910  6.4330  6.5321    10  b 
# reclass2  4.9246  4.9876  5.16236  5.03045  5.3546  5.6490    10   c
```